# Validar identificadores repetidos con C#

Tags: c#

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy haciendo tipo un chat con ASP .NET SQLServer.
Quiero validar para que muestre una sola vez el comentario "hola saludo 1" y luego abajo sus respectivas respuestas. La siguiente imagen del problema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cómo estás recorriendo los resultado de la consulta en C#? la verdad no conozco una manera de devolver como tu dices los resultados en SQL, pero puede que haya una solución por C#.

Comment: Es que así no se hace un chat tendrías que tener una tabla de muchos a muchos con IdUsuarioEnvia, IdUsuarioRecibe, FechaMensaje (datetime) y el mensaje

Comment: @Arnaldo, al título de tu pregunta "Validar identificadores repetidos con C#", ¿Tienes avanzado como mostrar la información de formulario web en asp.net? o ¿Cómo estás recuperando la información de tu chat?

Answer (score 2):

Tu base de datos parece que no está normalizada, pero aún así se puede hacer lo que deseas.

**SQL**
La manera más sencilla es desde la consulta SQL, primero obtener el comentario y después sus respuestas:

```
SELECT distinct IdComentario, Comentario FROM <tu tabla>
SELECT respuesta FROM <tu tabla> WHERE IdComentario = < x >
```

**C#**
Usa un DataTable y uno de sus métodos de ordenación.

De preferencia normaliza tu base de datos, es decir, una tabla "Comentarios" y una tabla dependiente "Respuestas".

Comment: La consulta es un inner join. tengo una tabla comentarios y una tabla respuesta. el idcomentario esta relacionado a fkrespuesta. la relacion es d 1 a muchos. un comentario puede tener muchas respuestas.

Comment: La manera fácil es no hacer un join, ejecuta primero la consulta que trae los comentarios, lo guardas en un DataTable y después la iteras ejecutando la segunda consulta.

Comment: gracias. dos consultas eran. igual no lo hice con datable. yo lo hago con data reader. gracias me sirvio tu idea.

Answer (score 0):

No estoy segura de la estructura de tu base de datos, pero me es confuso el porqué tienes el id del comentario duplicado, yo agregaría una columna para identificar a que chat se refiere y ejecutaría esto al querer insertar un nuevo comentario:

```
IF EXISTS (select Comentarion from Table
WHERE Comentario=@comentario AND IdChat = @Chat)
 BEGIN
    PRINT 'No insertar'
 END
 ELSE
 BEGIN
    INSERT INTO .....
END
```

Esto puede ser en un `trigger` o llamarlo en un `Stored Procedure`